# Is the significant location change service dependent upon the user enabling/disabling location services?

Tags: ios

In the location programming guide it says region monitoring is dependent upon if the user has disabled location services, but I didn't see it saying the same thing for significant location changes.

Does this mean getting significant location changes is independent of if the user had enabled/disabled location services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No form of location information is available if the user does not have location services enabled on their device.